# Does Windows Azure Caching Service support clusters?

Tags: caching, azure

Windows Azure Caching is [described](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsazure/features/caching/) as distributed, but the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg185678.aspx) states that the high availability feature is unavalable and that the [maximum cache size](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg618005.aspx) is 4GB.

The question is: is it possible to go over the 4GB size by creating a cluster of several caches, each 4GB in size? Or is 4GB the hard limit, and that 4GB is already clustered, supposedly of smaller caches?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have more than one cache.  I just tested by creating two namespaces 'gregolivera' and 'gregoliverb'.

Each cache namespace is managed separately, so this does not allow for creation of objects >4gb in size.  Objects will not 'bridge' between caches.

Comment: But will the same client application be able to leverage these two namespaces as a single, distributed cache cluster?

Comment: Update: after speaking to a Microsoft Technical Evangelist, he confirmed that 4GB is the maximum cache cluster size; you can't create a cluster composed of several 4 GB-sized nodes. So I'll mark this answer as accepted in the sense that you can create several caches but they will be distinct.

Answer (score 0):

High availability is indeed available for Windows Azure AppFabric Caching Service. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/ee790974.aspx for further details.

Comment: That article is for Windows Server AppFabric Caching.  Not applicable to Windows Azure AppFabric Caching.